# How to prove that rationals are not $G_\delta$ using Baire category theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

I have read the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set#Examples) about the proof. The outlines of the proof are:

1. Assume $\mathbb{Q}=\bigcap_n A_n$ where $A_n$ is dense and open.
2. Then, let $W_n=A_n \setminus \{q_n\}$ with $q_n$ is the $n$th rational in some enumeration. Then, $W_n$ is dense and open.
3. It has $\bigcap_n W_n =\emptyset$ as a contradiction.

I am wondering how the empty set of final step is concluded.

Comment: You know that $\mathbb{Q} \supset \bigcap W_n$ by construction. Now suppose by contradiction $\bigcap W_n \neq \emptyset$, then there must be some $q_N$ in your enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ so that $q_N \in \bigcap W_n$. However, $q_N \notin W_N \supset \bigcap W_n$, which yields a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

If $x \in \cap_n W_n$ then, for any $n$ we have  $x \in A_n$ and $x \neq q_n$. Hence $x \in \cap_n A_n=\mathbb Q$ but $x \neq q_n$ for each $n$. This is a contardiction because $q_n$'s exhaust $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks, it is a nice proof. I may abuse the definition of countable intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The irrationals are a $G_{\delta}$ set: $\Bbb R \backslash \Bbb Q = \cap_{n \in \Bbb N}\{q_n\}^c$ where $(q_n)$ is some enumeration of the rationals. Now suppose $\Bbb Q$ was a $G_{\delta}$ set. Then $\Bbb Q = \cap_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n$ where each $A_n$ is open and dense. Now look at the following intersection

\begin{equation}
\emptyset= \{\Bbb R \backslash \Bbb Q\}\cap\Bbb Q = \{\cap_{n \in \Bbb N}\{q_n\}^c\}\cap\{\cap_{n \in N}A_n\}
\end{equation}

which is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\emptyset = \cap_{n \in \Bbb N} \{A_n \cap \{q_n\}^c \} = \cap_{n \in \Bbb N}\{A_n \backslash \{q_n\}\}
\end{equation}

Now each $A_n\backslash \{q_n \} = W_n$ is open and dense. But since $\Bbb R$ is complete, $\cap_{n \in \Bbb N}W_n = \emptyset$ is not possible. So $\Bbb Q$ is not a $G_{\delta}$ set.